# Adding row in dplyr across a selected number of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, row, magrittr

While within `dplyr` workflow I would like to append a row across a selected number of columns.

## Desired results

Starting with the `mtcars`data and applying function(s) with the goal of adding string **`"A"`** to columns **`2:5`** the one should arrive at the following results:

```
                    mpg  cyl disp  hp  drat wt    qsec   vs am   gear carb
                    NA     A A     A   A    NA    NA     NA NA   NA   NA
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
```

The following criteria were met:

- For the columns with available index in `vars()` call the `"A"` string was added
- For the remaining columns the `NA` value was provided

## Approach

```
require(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(.cols = vars(2:5),
            .funs = add_row(. = "A", .before = 1))
```

Naturally, this results in an error message:

> Error: Unsupported index type: NULL

Hence my question: *how can I utilise `add_row`, or a similar approach, to force value across a set of columns initially passed via `vars()`?*

---

## Side notes

I don't mind doing this via `rbind` but I would like to keep my **`%>%`** workflow:

1. **`%>%`** - receive object
2. Add something across first row to columns `x:y` **`%>%`**
3. Add something across first row to columns `m:n` **`%>%`**
4. Other manipulations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the row then update:

```
mtcars %>% 
  head %>%
  add_row(.before = 1) %>% 
  mutate_at(.cols = vars(2:5),
            funs(ifelse(is.na(.), "A", .)))

#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1   NA   A    A   A    A    NA    NA NA NA   NA   NA
# 2 21.0   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 3 21.0   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 4 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 5 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 6 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# 7 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

**Note:** This will add `"A"` to any row that has NAs.